# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. For My PAP

Tags: actionscript-3

This is for my game of obstacles that I am creating and what is giving error is at the time of the player colliding with the end that appears the following error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   obstaculo_fla::MainTimeline/handleCollision()[obstaculo_fla.MainTimeline::frame9:55]
>
> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   obstaculo_fla::MainTimeline/handleCollision_final()[obstaculo_fla.MainTimeline::frame367:18]

This is the code:

```
player.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision_final)

function handleCollision_final( e:Event ):void
{
if(player.hitTestObject(nextum))
   {
       gotoAndPlay(368);
   }
   else
   {
       trace("MISS");
   }
} 

player.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision)

function handleCollision( e:Event ):void
{
if(player.hitTestObject(wall))
   {
       player.y-=20;
       gotoAndPlay(6);
   }
   else
   {
       trace("MISS");
   }
}
```

Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/actionscript-3/2098/understanding-the-error-1009-cannot-access-a-property-or-method-of-a-null-obje/6882/forgotten-event-listener#t=201703290934099227855

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried modifying your code with a *Drag* event (in a single scene), everything seem to be working OK. I've run in to a similar problem in the past, and found that I had to get rid of the event listeners. I've also found that I need a separate function to do that. Give this a shot:

```
player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision_final)

function handleCollision_final(e: Event): void {
    if (player.hitTestObject(nextum)) {
        removeELs(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ELs (EventListeners)
        gotoAndPlay(368);
    } else {
        trace("nextum: MISS");
    }
}

player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision)

function handleCollision(e: Event): void {
    if (player.hitTestObject(wall)) {
        player.y -= 20;
        removeELs(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ELs (EventListeners)
        gotoAndPlay(6);
    } else {
        trace("wall: MISS");
    }
}

// This probably won't work if you try 'removeEventListener' 
// from within the collision functions.
function removeELs() {
    player.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision)
    player.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision_final)
}
```

As you can see, I added the 'removeELs()' function at the bottom of your code.

Good luck